# Inkscape inx param defaults

Tags: inkscape

I am developing a extension for Inkscape and would like to set a param value based on a value that is set on a object. For example if the ID of the selected object is set to "myRect" how would I display that value in the extension dialog? Seems to me that there should be a way to tell Inkscape that I want a value displayed here from attribute "id", I have read through the documentation on Inkscapes wiki and searched the web but couldn't find any answers.

Comment: I have the same question

Comment: Could you find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.

The extension UI is built from the static .inx file.  There's no way for your extension code to modify that AFAIK.

It might be possible to have your extension rewrite the .inx file all the time.  But I imagine that this would be a horrible horrible approach.  Also I'm not sure how frequently inkscape reloads the .inx file.